# Check if a string contains a substring AND save the string from that point

Tags: java, string

Hello if a have the string:`String myString = "This is my good string.`,

I want to check if the word "my" is contained in myString, and so i want to transform myString in `myString = "my good string`.

I tryied this code per verify the subrstring in the string:

```
String myString = "this is my good string.";
String mySubString = "my";

if (myString.toLowerCase().contains(mySubString.toLowerCase()) {
  return true;
}
```

But now how can i take myString from "my..." to the end of that String?
Thank you!

Comment: Use: int positionOfMy = myString.indexOf("my"); to get position of "my" and String myTransformedString = myString.substring(positionOfMy); to get substring you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find out the index of word `"my"`from your original string.

```
int i = myString.indexOf(mySubString);
```

Then reassign your string to a substring that will begin at that index until the end of string.

```
myString = myString.substring(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

With regex :

```
myString = myString.replaceFirst(".*(?=my)", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

String s="this is my good string";

indexOf() finds the starting index of "my". substring() finds the String, that starts with "my".

```
    String st=s.substring(s.indexOf("my",0));
```